# How to create a wxWidgets app with Visual C++ on Raspberry

Tags: visual-c++, wxwidgets, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to make a C++ application with wxWidgets for raspberry on Visual studio.
I created a blink project from the templates and I only added the library wx.h in order to test the code and when I try to compile it fails because it doesn't find the library.
By the way, the blink project itself works fine. It only fails when I add the wx.h library.

`#include <wx-3.1\wx\wx.h>`

It's odd, because whe I open the file it has the right path.
Even intellisense detects the path correctly.
[image]

But I can't figure out what is causing the error.

I configured a remote connection to the raspberry:
[image]

And these are the errors displayed:
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to reflect the problem you're having or question you're asking, rather than just regurgitating the tags. Your title should be clear an descriptive enough to be of use to a future site user who is scanning a list of search results looking for a problem solution.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @EmmanuelLG, did you compiled the library yourself or use the pre-built version? Which version of the library do you use? Also, please show your include line from the project. And finally - the title of the question is too generic - please correct to make it specific.

Comment: I compiled it. It's the version 3.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to answer your question, e.g. you don't explain how do you build your project at all (e.g. do you use CMake?), but a couple of observations that may be helpful:

- wxWidgets headers are included as `<wx/wx.h>`, you definitely should *not* have the `wx-3.1` component and you must use slashes and not backslashes.
- You have to provide the compiler with the appropriate options, which usually happens by running `wx-config --cxxflags` under Unix systems (which may be hidden from you if you use CMake `FindwxWidgets` module which uses `wx-config` internally).